# Spring - AOP - Annotation code generation

Tags: spring, aop

I have got a problem, and I hope somebody can help me.

I use Spring framework, and I wish to generate a method inside one of my domain class...

I have got a Domain entity:

```
@Entity
class AbcDomain {
   private int id;

   @CustomAnnotation(p1="x1", p2="y1")
   private String a;

   @CustomAnnotation(p1="x2", p2="y2")
   private String b;

   @CustomAnnotation(p1="3", p2="y3")
   private int c;

   private Set<Integer> d;
   ... getters and setters
}
```

And I wish to generate a "m" method to this domain.
The methods contains the fileds, which got "CustomAnnotation" annotation like this:

```
@Entity
class AbcDomain {
    ... Prev code ...

    public String m() {
        if ( "x1".equals(a) ) // "x1" comes from the annotation's p1 param
          return "y1";        // "y1" comes from the annotation's p2 param

        if ( "x2".equals(b) ) // "x2" comes from the annotation's p1 param
          return "y2";        // "y2" comes from the annotation's p2 param

        if ( c == 3 )  // 3 comes from the annotation's p1 param
          return "y3"; // "y3" comes from the annotation's p1 param
    }
}
```

I am very new in spring and aop, can anybody help me where can I find the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need Compile Time AspectJ then you can do something called [Inter-Type-Declaration](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-interType.html) (this technic is heavily used in Spring Roo, so if you want to have a complete example create a spring roo project).

```
privileged aspect AbcDomain_Extension {

    public String m() {
        if ( "x1".equals(a) ) // "x1" comes from the annotation's p1 param
          return "y1";        // "y1" comes from the annotation's p2 param

        if ( "x2".equals(b) ) // "x2" comes from the annotation's p1 param
          return "y2";        // "y2" comes from the annotation's p2 param

        if ( c == 3 )  // 3 comes from the annotation's p1 param
          return "y3"; // "y3" comes from the annotation's p1 param
    }

}
```